# Boot Windows guest from VDI with EFI

Tags: windows-7, boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine, uefi

**Goal**: create a VirtualBox machine to boot my current Windows 7 installation in both Windows and Linux hosts.

**Resources** I read several questions here and [this](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/10/30/how-to-convert-windows-installations-to-virtual-machine-images/) guide.

What I did:

1. make a `vhdx` clone of my Windows partition using `disk2vhd`
2. convert to `vdi`: `VBoxManage.exe clonemedium disk "Windows 7.vhdx" "Windows 7.vdi" --format vdi`
3. in VBox created a new Windows 7 64-bit machine
4. add the newly created `vdi` file under SATA controllers
5. enable the EFI support in settings > system > motherboard
6. boot the machine

It lands to a UEFI shell instead of booting my Windows system.
What am I missing?

Comment: Is your physical Windows 7 system UEFI-bootable?

Comment: Yes, it runs on an ASUS VivoBook Pro that uses the new EFI sistem.